# Como usar a tag rel_canonical quando dois dominios apontam para o mesmo site?

Tags: html

Eu tenho dois dominios

```
exemple.com
exemple.tk
```

eles apontam para o mesmo conteúdo incluindo todas as suas sub-paginas

como eu uso a tag tag `rel_canonical` ?

Answer (score 1):

Por questões de SEO, você deve escolher um pra ser o seu domínio principal, e o outro você pode criar um redirecionamento 301.

Deixar dois domínios separados e apontando pro mesmo site, mostrando o mesmo conteúdo é ruim, porque o Google e outros buscadores vão entender que aquele conteúdo é uma copia e isso faz o pagerank cair.

Pro seu caso em especifico, a tag `canonical` não irá resolver, porque ela só pode apontar pra o conteúdo principal que deve estar no mesmo domínio onde ela foi inserida.

Os usos mais comuns da tag canonical são:

Página onde a tag foi atribuida: http://exemplo.com.br/tag-canonical/

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://exemplo.com.br/tag-canonical/">
```

Evita que os buscadores entendam como conteúdo duplicado as seguintes páginas:

- http://exemplo.com.br/tag-canonical
- http://exemplo.com.br/tag-canonical/?comentario=3820

Acho que já deu pra sacar mais ou menos qual a utilização dessa tag

Só pra frizar, novamente, se tiver dois domínios, escolha um pra ser o principal e no outro aponte um redirecionamento 301 para seu domínio principal.